# Is the boundary of a compact connected subset of $\mathbb R^n, n>1$ connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ be compact and connected, where $n\ge2$. Is the boundary $\partial A$ connected?

Comment: If $A$ is not connected, the answer is clearly no. For example, take $A=\{ a,b \}$ a set with two points.

Comment: No, but see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298125/connected-ness-of-the-boundary-of-convex-sets-in-mathbb-rn-n1-under-a) for the question, whether the boundary of every compact convex set in $ℝ^n$ , $n>1$ is connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Counter-example: $A = [0, 1] \subset \Bbb R $.

---

No. Counter-example: $A = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 2\} \subset \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Crostul, sorry, you answered too fast! I was about to edit. $n>1$.

Comment: I updated the answer.