Is connected open set minus compact convex set connected?
Given a connected open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $K\subset \Omega$ be compact. Denote the convex hull of $K$ by $C$. Is it true that $\Omega-C$ is still connected? Is it possible to generalize this to normed vector space?
If $n=1$, then this is not true because we can just take $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $K=[1/4,3/4]$. But I only care about the case that $n\geq 2$.
Originally I just want to prove that there exists a compact set $S$ that contains $K$ such that $\Omega-S$ is connected. The following illustration probably shows why I am considering the convex hull.

Update: I like Pranay's counterexample. However, I still want to solve my original problem. That is, for any connected open set $\Omega$ and a compact set $K\subset\Omega$, can I always find a compact set $S$ that contains $K$ such that $\Omega-S$ is still connected? I believe that this statement is true. Since $K$ is compact, its distance $d$ to the boundary of $\Omega$ is positive. Now consider the set $S=\{x\in \Omega: \text{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)\geq d\}$, which is compact when $\Omega$ is bounded. Then I think $\Omega-S=\{x\in \Omega: \text{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)<d\}$ is a connected set but I don't know how to prove it. In the case that $\Omega$ is not bounded, since $K$ is compact, I can take some bounded connected subset of $\Omega$ that contains $K$ so that I can use the argument above.
Update 2: Let me give some motivations for this problem. Given a holomorphic function $f:\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ ($n\geq 2$). I want to show that the zero set $Z(f):=\{z\in \Omega:f(z)=0\}$ of $f$ cannot be contained in any compact subset $K\subset\Omega$ (unless $Z(f)$ is empty). If $\Omega-K$ is connected, then by Hartogs's extension theorem, $1/f$ is a holomorphic function defined on $\Omega-K$ that can be extended to a holomorphic function on $\Omega$. This is then a contradiction because $1/f$ would be equal to $\infty$ on $K$. In general, we don't know whether $\Omega-K$ is compact, but my intuition suggests that I can find a larger compact set $S$ that contains $K$ such that $\Omega-S$ is still connected (so that I can still apply the above argument). For example, suppose there exists a holomorphic function $f$ defined on the unit ball $B_1:=\{(z_1,z_2):|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2< 1\}\subset \mathbb{C}^2$ such that $Z(f)\subset K:=\{(z_1,z_2):|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=0.5\}$. $B_1-K$ clearly has two components. However, $K\subset \overline{B_{0.5}}$ (the closed ball of radius $0.5$), and $B_1-\overline{B_{0.5}}$ is connected. This them implies such $f$ doesn't exist.
Related link: An application of Hartogs' theorem

I think you might want to assume that $K $ is a compact convex subset of $\Omega$ to start with. Taking the convex hull may easily disturb connectedness. If you do assume $K$ to be convex to start with, this might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1298125/27978

@SeverinSchraven I don't think your $K$ is compact.

@Rmal Indeed, classic late night post.

I think to prove your updated question you need some version of Alexander duality, but if you can't make some niceness condition on $K$ (like it being locally contractible) then you'll need something like Cech cohomology, which will get real messy real fast.

@MartianInvader Sadly I don't know enough things about cohomology.

Consider the union of the two open balls $\Omega = B_1(-1+\epsilon,0,\ldots,0) \cup B_1(1-\epsilon,0,\ldots,0)$ for some small $\epsilon>0$. That’s a connected open set.
Now consider the union of two closed balls $K = B_{1/2}(-1/2,0,\ldots,0) \cup B_{1/2}(1/2,0,\ldots,0)$. That’s a compact set inside $\Omega$.
Clearly removing the convex hull $C$ of $K$ from $\Omega$ gives a disconnected set.
Here's an illustration in 2 dimensions:


Answer to the updated question:
Take the open set $\Omega$ to be the open annulus centred at the origin and with inner and outer radii $1$ and $4$. Clearly, it’s connected. Take the compact subset $K$ to be the closed annulus centred at the origin and with inner and outer radii $2$ and $3$. It is easy to see that removing any compact subset $S$ containing $K$ from $\Omega$ gives a disconnected set.

For a simpler version, take $\Omega$ to be the convex hull of the points $(x, \pm 2x)$ and $C$ to be the points $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$.

@copper.hat Wouldn't the convex hull of $(x,\pm2x)$ be the entire plane? Is there a restriction on $x$?

Sorry, I mean the points between the two lines, not the convex hull. However, the resulting set is closed not open, so please ignore my comment.

Hi,  I like your counterexample. However, I still want to solve my original problem. May you have a look of my update to the post?

@Rmal see my updated answer.

@Pranay Notice that I didn't require $S$ to be a subset of $\Omega$. In your example, I can just take $S$ to be the disk of radius 3.

@Rmal. Ah right! Then your statement might be true. Let me think more about this.

@Pranay Now I believe that my statement is true. Since $K$ is compact, its distance $d$ to the boundary of $\Omega$ is positive. Now consider the set $S={x\in \Omega: \text{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)\geq d}$, which is compact when $\Omega$ is bounded. Then I think $\Omega-S={x\in \Omega: \text{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)<d}$ is a connected set but I don't know how to prove it. In the case that $\Omega$ is not bounded, since $K$ is compact, I can take some bounded connected subset of $\Omega$ that contains $K$ so that I can use the argument above.

@Rmal. I had exactly the same idea. But in the annulus example, the boundary of $\Omega$ has two components, inner and outer circles, so one has to be careful. What we need is the "outer boundary", but I have to think more about how to make this precise.

@Rmal. If $\Omega$ is bounded, why can't you simply take $S$ to be a compact set containing $\Omega$? Then the difference is empty, which is connected.

@Pranay Surely I don't want the complement to be empty. You can probably read my update to understand my motivation for this problem.

For the updated question.
If one can assume that $\Omega$ is bounded, then the statement is true.
(In the degenerate case one can just take $S=\overline \Omega$ so $\Omega\setminus S$ is empty hence connected. Hence I moreover require that $\Omega \not\subseteq S$.)
Then since $\Omega\setminus K$ is open, it contains an open ball $B$. Let $S = \overline\Omega\setminus B$. This is closed and therefore compact, and $\Omega\setminus S = B$ is connected.
I am not sure if it can be assumed that $\Omega$ is bounded. (For example, when $K$ is connected, then we can safely assume this, because we can take open ball $B_R$ of radius large enough s.t. $K\subset B_R$, and then consider $\Omega \cap B_R$. Although this can be disconnected, one can take its (only) connected component that ontains $K$, as the new $\Omega$.)

We're given $\Omega$ open and $K \subseteq \Omega$ compact. Surely $K$ is bounded. If $\Omega$ is not bounded, we can always find an open and bounded $\Omega'$ with $K \subseteq \Omega' \subseteq \Omega$. So w.l.o.g. $\Omega$ can be assumed to be bounded.

@8bc3457f Yes, but I want to ensure the new $\Omega'$ is also connected

Oh! Right, thanks fo reminding. Maybe, if we obtained an $\Omega'$ which is not connected, consider pairs of its components. For each of them find a path in $\Omega$ connecting these components and add an $\varepsilon$-nbhd of that path to $\Omega'$.

The problem remains, if $\Omega'$ had infinitely many components… But are there even such examples? I think I can build sufficiently degenerate $\Omega'$ and $\Omega$. But would it be possible to use compactness of $K$ to restrict to finitely many components of $\Omega'$?  Edit: just read the answer of Pranay, so never mind.
